# Как правильно передать Ajax запрос на веб сервис

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5, java-ee

```js
 $("#submit").on('click',function () {


$.ajax({

    url:"http://localhost:8080/webtest/service",
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"application/json",
    success:function () {
        alert("Ajax request success");
    },
    error:function () {
        alert("look at the response headers for error!")
    }

});

});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tests</title>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<form">


    <label for = "username">UserName:</label>
    <input id = "username"><br>
    <label for = "email">Email:</label>
    <input id = "email" type="email"><br>
    <label for = "password">Password:</label>
    <input id = "password" type="password"><br>
    <input id = "submit" type="button" value="Send!">

</form>


<script src="requests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@WebServlet(name = "webService" , urlPatterns = "/service")
public class WebServiceDemo extends HttpServlet {

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        response.getWriter().print("In the if else DO POST METHOD");

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    **//When the server starts i got response from here!**
    response.getWriter().print("Hello from servlet");

    }
  }
```

Знакомлюсь с Ajax запросами. Что из данного кода не верно ? При попытке передать запрос отчёт об ошибки! Получаю возврат от сервера 200! Но выводится код Jquery Ajax функции error с алертом! Почему ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax запрос написан правильно, скорее всего ошибка в серверной части. В запросе к серверу указано, что должны вернуться данные в виде JSON (application/json), но у Вас возвращается просто строка

> response.getWriter().print("In the if else DO POST METHOD");.

По пробуйте вернуть данные как нибудь так

> response.getWriter().print({"string":"In the if else DO POST METHOD"})

А в javascript'е измените метод success

```js
success: function (responce) {
  alert(responce.string);
}
```

Можно еще по пробовать просто указать dataType: "text/plain"

```js
$.ajax({

    url:"http://localhost:8080/webtest/service",
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"text/plain",
    success:function () {
        alert("Ajax request success");
    },
    error:function () {
        alert("look at the response headers for error!")
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Сам недавно ознакомился с вопросом и делаю так:

```js
function loadDoc()
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
                    {
                        processJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                }

                var url = 'your url';

                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            function processJSON(json) {

                if (typeof JSON !== "undefined") {
                    json = JSON.parse(json);
                  
                  //your code
                  
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка - вот тут:

```
dataType: "application/json",
```

Во-первых, параметр `dataType` в jquery - это совсем не mime-тип. Во-вторых, ваш сервис возвращает совсем не json!

В соответствии с [документацией](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), вам в вашем случае больше подойдет

```
dataType: "text",
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Не понимаю ваш ответ! Вот я поменял. Добавляю  код с верху.
Чтото нетак с AJAX функцией, что это за ошибка ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.